# grep -Pzo: how to make redirected output be an ASCII text (instead of data)?

Tags: grep

```
$ cat t2.c
xxx

$ grep -Pzo xxx t2.c
xxx

$ grep -Pzo xxx t2.c > out1 && file out1
out1: data
```

Here we see that `out1` is a `data` (instead of an `ASCII text`). How to make it be an ASCII text?

UPD. The `-z` is needed for the multi-line match. Here is an updated example:

```
$ cat t2.c
xxx
yyy
zzz

$ grep -Pzo '(?s)xxx.*zzz' t2.c
xxx
yyy
zzz

$ grep -Pzo '(?s)xxx.*zzz' t2.c > out1 && file out1
out1: data
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your own example,

```
echo xxx >t2.c

grep -Pzo xxx t2.c > out1 && file out1
out1: data

grep -Po xxx t2.c > out1 && file out1
out1: ASCII text
```

The `-z` flag to `grep` is intended to be used with NULL-terminated data, both for input and - here more importantly - for output. Quoting from the documentation (`man grep`):

> **`-z, --null-data`** Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero  byte  (the  ASCII NUL  character)  instead  of  a newline.  Like the -Z or --null option, this option can be used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.

You can see this if you use a tool like `od`:

```
$ od -c out1
0000000   x   x   x  \0
0000004
```

That `\0` at the end is the NULL. The `file` command sees the NULL character and correctly determines that the file cannot be ASCII - or even any other type of text. The fall-back point is the indeterminate `data`, which is what you're seeing.

Solution? Don't use `-z` unless you expect your input to provide NULL-terminated records *and* for your output also to be delimited with NULL-terminated records. Alternatively, you can simply remove the NULL before saving to a file:

```
$ grep -Pzo xxx t2.c | tr -d '\0' > out1  && file out1
out1: ASCII text, with no line terminators
```

Comment: As title says: `grep -Pzo`. I.e. the `-z` is needed. See UPD.

Comment: @pmor we cannot guess that it is needed. I suspect what you want is to do a multi-line match, but then you seem to also want to capture the output in a file and do something. This means that `grep -z` isn't the best option but we cannot suggest a better one if you don't explain what the final objective is (see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)). So please edit your question and explain the entire thing you are trying to achieve so we can give you a correct answer. That said, are you maybe looking for `grep -Pzo '(?s)xxx.*zzz' t2.c | tr -d '\0'`?

Comment: @terdon Yes, I am doing the multi-line match and need to redirtect the output to a file which is ASCII text. Yes, the `grep -Pzo '(?s)xxx.*zzz' t2.c | tr -d '\0'` is a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Surely you mean `tr '\0' '\n'` or similar otherwise the result won't be a valid POSIX text file (won't end in `\n`).